# Как сделать вывод HashMap?

Tags: java, сортировка

На входе я получаю строку : `String s = "сапог сарай арбуз болт бокс биржа"`
Нужно преобразовать строку в такую структуру данных, которая группирует слова по первой букве в слове. Затем вывести только группы, содержащие более одного элемента.

Как вывести группы содержащие более одного элемента ?

Вот мой код :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String[] s1 = s.split(" ");
    Arrays.sort(s1);
    Map<Character, List<String» map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String word : s1) {
        Character key = word.charAt(0);
        List<String> list = map.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(key, list);
        }
        list.add(word);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В цикле перебирайте элементы словаря и фильтруйте элементы, выводя те, которых от 2 и больше:

```
String s = "сапог сарай арбуз болт бокс биржа";

Map<Character, List<String>> items = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : s.split(" ")) {
    Character key = word.charAt(0);
    List<String> list = items.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        items.put(key, list);
    }
    list.add(word);
}
System.out.println(items);
// {а=[арбуз], с=[сапог, сарай], б=[болт, бокс, биржа]}

for (Map.Entry<Character, List<String>> entry : items.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().size() <= 1) {
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
// с: [сапог, сарай]
// б: [болт, бокс, биржа]

// Получение ключей, чьи списки имеют больше 1 элемента
List<Character> wordGroups = items.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(wordGroups);
// [б, с]
```

---

Если у вас `java 8`, то код с добавление списка в элемент можно упростить через метод [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
for (String word : s.split(" ")) {
    Character key = word.charAt(0);
    List<String> list = items.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>());
    list.add(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В первом стриме группируем слова по первому симову, во втором - фильтруем группы размером больше, чем 1, объединяем группу в строку и выводим.

```
    String s = "сапог сарай арбуз болт бокс биржа";
    String[] words = s.split(" ");

    Map<Character, List<String>> map = Arrays
            .stream(words)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word.charAt(0)));
    map.keySet()
            .stream()
            .map(map::get)
            .filter(list -> list.size() > 1)
            .map(list -> String.join(" ", list))
            .forEach(System.out::println);

//болт бокс биржа
//сапог сарай
```